# Generate a random and reproducible hashcode for a string comparable to ora_hash

Tags: java, string, oracle, random, hashcode

I have the requirement to generate random but reproducible numbers for arbitrary strings in Java. For the same requirement in SQL I have used the function [`ORA_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e23381/row_functions057.htm#OLAXS450) provided by Oracle:

> ORA_HASH generates hash values for an expression. You can use it to randomly assign a set of values into several buckets for analysis, or to generate a set of random numbers.

The function has three parameters: the expression to hash, the maximum bucket number, and a seed. For my purposes in SQL the maximum bucket number has been set to the maximum allowed value.

My idea is to implement `ORA_HASH` in Java (with maximum bucket number). For that purpose I want to combine `String.hashCode()` with a random seed.

However, I have no idea how to combine the hashcode and the seed such that

1. no additional hash collision emerges (`xor` probably don't satisfy this requirement)
2. neither the seed nor the original expressions are (easily) reproducible from the result (a simple `+` don't satisfy this requirement)

Any idea for a better solution?

**Edit in reply to comments**

I need (almost) unique pseudo-identifiers for strings to make them anonymized. I would favour "anonymized"/"hard to reverse" over "almost unique"/"less collisions". My impression is that a high `max_bucket_number` in `ora_hash` supports "less collisions" and `seed` supports "hard to reverse". Standard message digests (SHA, MD5) are not suitable because the strings to be hashed come from a dictionary; without a seed/salt a rainbow table attack would reveal the words. Some algorithms using a salt (e.g. bcrypt) generates hashes which are very long. `ora_hash` seems to be the best trade-off.

Comment: Are you stuck with using `ORA_HASH` in the database? If not, why not use a standard hashing algorithm that both Oracle and Java support? From Oracle you can use [`dbms_crypto`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65675). (None of these are 'random' - you might want to rephrase that...)

Comment: It is a complete different context. I have no Oracle available here, just borrowed the idea of `ora_hash`. Moreover, there is no need that the results are identical. As far as I understand `ora_hash` is "random" as the seed is random: that is if you don't know the seed you can't predict the result.

Comment: How are you going to use this? I ask because you want two conditions that normally shouldn't be needed simultaneously. Hashing for things like "group by" in a database needs to manage collisions, but there is no requirement that "un-hashing" be extraordinarily difficult. Hashing for things like passwords needs to be exceptionally hard to reverse, but there is no particular concern about collisions. There are very good algorithms for either application. Why do you need BOTH conditions at the same time?

Comment: @mathguy Edited the question to answer your valid point!